# Dealing with mods with poor reading comprehension?

Tags: discussion

My flag:

> Not an Answer flag declined, with reason that it is a wrong answer or technically innacurate. The answer is actually RIGHT and ACCURATE, however, it does not answer the question asked. Therefore the flag "does not attempt to answer the question" applies. This is exactly what the Not an Answer flag is for. Please coach the moderator on this. – AaronLS Oct 22 at 22:26

Moderator Response:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This mod clearly can't see that no one has claimed the answer is inaccurate or wrong.  In fact, the answer is completely accurate and factual, however is in no way relevant to the question asked.  It's akin to answering the question "Is peanut butter good for you?" with an answer of "Peanut butter is brownish color"

I flagged an item to clarify a flag, however it was declined again with the same reason, as if completely ignoring the fact that I made it absolutely clear I was not flagging it because I believed it was wrong or inaccurate.  I understand that an answer that is wrong or inaccurate should simply be downvoted. The answer given is an accurate statement, but is not relevant to the question.

The reason for the decline doesn't apply to this answer.  I've made this clear in my flag, but they didn't address this.

I imagine some will give alternative reasons that the "Not an Answer" flag does not apply here, but the point is that if the mod is incapable of articulating this themselves then they are unqualified to be a moderator.  If there is a legitimate reason to decline the flag, then so be it, but a moderator should be capable of articulating that.

The answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346669/84206

Comment: NNA flags are only for posts that are not an answer _at all_. You are supposed to down vote the answer in this case.

Comment: You do realise you hadn't flagged that post prior to flagging it with the text above, right? ie: there's no context as to what you're clarifying, the text of your message reads as "this answer's fine" - so err, I can't see how you figure there'd be any other response?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/149/

Comment: Our definition of "not an answer" may be non-intuitive but it is very clear cut. Either way it's not worth getting too worked up over a single flag, even though one may be in the right.

Comment: If a community elects a moderator with poor reading comprehension, the community is the problem.

Comment: `If there is a legitimate reason to decline the flag, then so be it, but a moderator should be capable of articulating that.`..... I am sure most mods would love to be able to give personalized responses to every single flag, but in the time it takes them to write a personalized "this is why I rejected your flag", they could have handled several additional flags.  I'd rather have them handling flags than responding to each and every rejection.

Comment: *however is in no way relevant to the question asked* - How is that different from being wrong?

Answer (score 20):

Not an Answer (NAA) flags are there to indicate that someone misused the Answer button to post a question, or similarly something that is not an answer to *anything*. Wether or not an actual answer (like this is) is relevant to the post is not the moderator's job to decide and thus you should not flag those posts as NAA. Downvote them if you deem it necessary and leave a comment.

By the way, implying that mods have poor reading comprehension because *you* do not understand the meaning of the NAA flag is a little rude.

Comment: I did not imply mods has poor reading comprehension because I did not understand the NAA flag. In fact, I acknowledged that perhaps there was a legitimate reason for the flag decline. My evidence of their lack of reading comprehension is that fact they responded to "The answer is actually RIGHT and ACCURATE" with a response of "should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".  It's a statement of fact, not meant to be an insult, but an opportunity for improvement.

Answer (score 10):

This would be a proper "not an answer":

> I have the same problem plz halp send solution to pekka5000@gmail.com

or

> I make $8,000 a month from home using Google! Want to find out how?

If an answer is clearly attempting to answer the question, it is not "Not an answer" even though the author may have gotten something so completely wrong that they're actually not answering the question at all.

By our definition, that still is an *incorrect* answer, not none at all.

Answer (score 9):

Moderators aren't there to do anything about the accuracy of a post.  They're not to be regarded as subject-matter experts, since it very may well be a moderator handling your flag that *doesn't* know about this particular software's intricacies.

If you feel that an answer does not satisfy, you may comment *and* downvote to that effect.  Mod flags are only useful in situations when a post is actively harmful or can't be acted upon by someone like yourself in the community; namely, the post is spammy or offensive.